# React website reloading and crashing on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, debugging, mobile-safari

We have two websites built the same way. Different content but they both suffer from the same glitch mobile where they will randomly reload whilst you’re scrolling. Shortly after the page will crash with a problem repeatedly occurred. It takes 20-30 seconds for the first reload and 20-30 again for the death crash. Any advice appreciated. They are ok on desktop.

The sites are [www.DrPepe.app](http://www.DrPepe.app) and trendin.ai